# Not getting efficient result from Tesseract OCR as newocr producing

Tags: android, opencv, ocr, tesseract, text-recognition

I am working on an app where i need to identify text from an image and what could be the better way than using Tesseract. As Tesseract is an open source and widely accepted. I have used Tesseract in my app. So, i am getting images from user and then applying 2-3 operations on image to improve chances of getting result but i am not getting expected result.

Java Code ->

```
    final Bitmap tessBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tessBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, paint);

    Mat tessMat = new Mat();

    Utils.bitmapToMat(tessBitmap, tessMat);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(tessMat, tessMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    Imgproc.threshold(tessMat, tessMat, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

    final Bitmap newTessBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tessMat.width(), tessMat.height(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    Utils.matToBitmap(tessMat, newTessBitmap);

    final Bitmap finalTessBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newTessBitmap.getWidth(), newTessBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas tessCanvas = new Canvas(finalTessBitmap);
    Paint tessPaint = new Paint();
    tessPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    tessCanvas.drawBitmap(newTessBitmap, 0, 0, tessPaint);
```

and then passing this bitmap to tesseract to get output but not getting efficient and sometimes i dont even get anything in output. I have compared my result with one online website https://www.newocr.com/ .

Which is also using tesseract in back end as it is claiming. i have also tried to contact them via email but coudlnt get anything from them.

```
mTess = new TessBaseAPI();
tessModelPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/tesseract/";
mTess.init(tessModelPath, "eng", TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY);                                 mTess.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.PageSegMode.PSM_AUTO);
mTess.setImage(finalTessBitmap);
```

This is the base Tesseract code. Please help me solve my issue. Thanks...

Given below is the image i get after applying above mentioned operation but when i pass it to tesseract i did not get anything but when passing to newocr.com website it is producing exact text.

[image]

Result from newOcr.

This image is for results.

[image: Check this image for results.]

Please suggest me about what to do if you have any idea.

After Digging more and running the same image in python code i have found out that in python pytesseract it works like charm and producing exact output as newocr. But when i run in android it doesnt work that well. so may be the issue is with API of Tesseract. So, now if you know anything still which i can do to improve accuracy. Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JimGrigoryan i also got surprised with their results and that is why i mailed them for what kind of image processing they do? but could'nt get anything. And i know that there are api available but i want to implement this offline. so i just want to know how can i improve the results. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tesseract 8UIBw.jpg -
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 613
Tillamook
```

It was without any preprocessing...

```
$ tesseract -v
tesseract 4.0.0-253-g3948
 leptonica-1.76.0 (Dec 14 2018, 15:34:47) [MSC v.1916 LIB Release x64]
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 9b : libpng 1.6.35 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer as i couldnt understand what you are trying to say? @user898678

Comment: It was reaction for "Please suggest me about what to do if you have any idea." and "I doubt newocr is using Tesseract as they claim." - tesseract version 4 process it without any preprocessing.

Comment: I have also observed same thing when i tried to run in python. Now i need something which can either optimize library or some image processing which will be needed for Tess-Two to produce Accurate Output.